# iPhone Original Notepad Tutorial?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to find a simple or advanced notepad tutorial. Like the one used in the iphone app bundle.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? When you say "simple notepad tutorial or advanced" do you mean you want source code so something like Apple's notepad app?

Comment: Yes source code with tutorial somthing i can learn from

Answer (score -1):

if I have not misunderstand your question, I think that you want know how did the Notepad app was build .... I assume that is base UITableView , each row is a cell, so I think it is not hard to clone the Notepad app .